# What are the meanings of "difference-in-differences" and "causal estimand"?

Tags: econometrics, definition, causal-inference

In [one discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/527119/319998), I saw the answer containing two words that I think can be used interchangeably, but I am not sure if it's the case.

> I simply state in other posts that the "generalized" **difference-in-differences **estimator** may accommodate intermittent exposures.

> Now it's important to note that the **causal estimand** is plausibly unbiased if we assume constant treatment effects.

So, I want to know whether **difference-in-differences estimator** and **causal estimand** have similar meanings and are they all about the coefficient of the variable **$Treatment \times Post$** in a DiD setting?

Comment: IMHO, these two words should be the same in any DID setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference-in-differences “estimator” is a method used to “estimate” a target parameter of interest. That parameter is also commonly referred to as the causal “estimand” (*that which is to be estimated*), at least in econometric circles. I also see it used quite frequently in reference to “treatment effects” in applied clinical trials. In short, it’s a quantity to be estimated in a statistical model.

Comment: So, is it mostly the coefficients of  **post*treat** variable?

Comment: Yes. But in the interest of being precise, the causal *estimand* is the target parameter. The coefficient we obtain for the target quantity (i.e., the product term) *is* the difference-in-differences estimate. It's inappropriate to call the coefficient in your regression output your causal estimand. Rather, it's your *estimate* of the causal *estimand*. Just be mindful of this subtle difference when you're writing up your findings.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, in a standard DID y = a1 + a2*post + a3*treat  +  a4*post*treat. So. in short, I may understand that **causal estimand** is **post * treat**, and **difference-in-differences estimator** is **a4**, is it correct ?

Comment: No. Ignore the variables for a moment. The parameter $\alpha_4$ attached to the product term is the *causal estimand*. It's something we want to *estimate*. Once we actually estimate it using software, then we call $\hat{\alpha}_4$ our difference-in-differences estimate.